# How to output values from 2 different groups onto a single line?

Tags: xslt, sum, grouping

I have a file of employees that receive different types of earnings per pay period. Each employee can have from 1 to 3 different earning flag types (A, B, C) and these earnings can be for different dates.

For each employee I would like to sum the amounts together if the record has the same earning flag and date. If there is not an earning for say B then there should be a 0 in the B place.

I would like the output to be on the same line if possible to make readability and verification easier. This is the part I am having trouble with.

I have grouped by EmployeeID, EarningFlag, and Date. Then I summed the amounts for each grouping. The output though goes on separate lines and is a mess. I have no idea how to put a zero in place if there is no such earning flag on that date for the employee.

Example XML:

```
<Entry>
    <EmployeeName>Bob Stevens</EmployeeName>
    <EmployeeID>123</EmployeeID>
    <EarningFlag>A</EarningFlag>
    <Date>2019-04-01</Date>
    <Amount>2031.54</Amount>
</Entry>
<Entry>
    <EmployeeName>Bob Stevens</EmployeeName>
    <EmployeeID>123</EmployeeID>
    <EarningFlag>A</EarningFlag>
    <Date>2019-04-01</Date>
    <Amount>30.74</Amount>
</Entry>
<Entry>
    <EmployeeName>Bob Stevens</EmployeeName>
    <EmployeeID>123</EmployeeID>
    <EarningFlag>B</EarningFlag>
    <Date>2019-04-01</Date>
    <Amount>1.63</Amount>
</Entry>
<Entry>
    <EmployeeName>Samantha Philips</EmployeeName>
    <EmployeeID>036</EmployeeID>
    <EarningFlag>C</EarningFlag>
    <Date>2019-04-01</Date>
    <Amount>631.54</Amount>
</Entry>
<Entry>
    <EmployeeName>Samantha Philips</EmployeeName>
    <EmployeeID>036</EmployeeID>
    <EarningFlag>C</EarningFlag>
    <Date>2019-04-01</Date>
    <Amount>3771.33</Amount>
</Entry>
<Entry>
    <EmployeeName>Samantha Philips</EmployeeName>
    <EmployeeID>036</EmployeeID>
    <EarningFlag>A</EarningFlag>
    <Date>2019-04-01</Date>
    <Amount>631.54</Amount>
</Entry>
<Entry>
    <EmployeeName>Samantha Philips</EmployeeName>
    <EmployeeID>036</EmployeeID>
    <EarningFlag>B</EarningFlag>
    <Date>2019-03-07</Date>
    <Amount>3771.33</Amount>
</Entry>
```

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Entry" group-by="concat(EmployeeID,Date,EarningFlag)">

   <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>  

   <xsl:value-of select="EmployeeID"/>
   <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>

   <xsl:value-of select="EmployeeName"/>
   <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>

   <xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
   <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>

   <xsl:if test="EarningFlag='A'">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Amount)"/>
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
   <xsl:if test="EarningFlag='B'">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Amount)"/>
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
   <xsl:if test="EarningFlag='C'">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Amount)"/>
   </xsl:if>

</xsl:for-each-group>

My actual results are:
123,Bob Stevens,2019-04-04,2062.28123,Bob Stevens,2019-04-04,1.63,
036,Samantha Philips,2019-03-07,3771.33,
036,Samantha Philips,2019-04-01,631.54,036,Samantha Philips,2019-04-01,3771.33

The expected output would be in the order of Employee ID, Employee Name, Date, A, B, C.

123,Bob Stevens,2019-04-01,2062.28,1.63,0
036,Samantha Philips,2019-03-07,0,3771.33,0
036,Samantha Philips,2019-04-01,631.54,0,3771.33


Is this even possible???

Thank you for any help.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to do:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Entry" group-by="concat(EmployeeID,Date)">

    <xsl:sort select="EmployeeID"/>  
    <xsl:sort select="Date"/>  

    <xsl:value-of select="EmployeeID"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>

    <xsl:value-of select="EmployeeName"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>

    <xsl:value-of select="Date"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>

    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()[EarningFlag='A']/Amount)"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>

    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()[EarningFlag='B']/Amount)"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>

    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()[EarningFlag='C']/Amount)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the answer from @michael.hor257k, you can also write

```
 <xsl:for-each-group select="Entry" group-by="concat(EmployeeID,Date)">

    <xsl:sort select="EmployeeID"/>  
    <xsl:sort select="Date"/>  

    <xsl:value-of select="EmployeeID, EmployeeName, Date,
                          sum(current-group([EarningFlag='A']/Amount),
                          sum(current-group()[EarningFlag='B']/Amount,
                          sum(current-group()[EarningFlag='C']/Amount"
                  separator=","/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

</xsl:for-each-group>
```